# number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length error in R

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I have the following loop that I am trying to run but I keep getting the error "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length". Can anyone help me as to why this is happening? Also, I need to somehow include my angles vector into my matrix and don't know how. Here is my loop so far:

```
anglematrix <- numeric()
for(i in 1:length(fish2$X))
{
    a1 <- as.numeric(fish2[1, c(1,2)])
    a2 <- as.numeric(fish2[1 + 1, c(1,2)])
    a3 <- as.numeric(fish2[1 + 2, c(1,2)])

    angles <- Angle(a1, a2, a3, label=FALSE)
    anglematrix[i] <- matrix(NA, nrow=length(fish2$X)-2, ncol=1)
}
```

Here is the structure of my data set with the first six lines

```
structure(list(X = c(147.8333333, 148.5, 151.1666667, 154.5,158.1666667, 161.5), Y = c(258.5, 258.8333333, 260.8333333, 264.5,266.5, 269.5)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

output should be 176 angle calculations in a single column within the matrix. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fihisning a for loop for angle data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53860770/fihisning-a-for-loop-for-angle-data)

Comment: it is a duplicate. I just forgot to delete the original question. Fixed now. Created a new question because the previous one got too messy with edits

Comment: For future reference you should not really delete and replace questions. You should just edit the existing ones to fix problems.  I still see problems with the current version such as that you do not provide actual data (use `dput` for this).

Comment: sorry I am new to this website and R. I added the structure of the data set and the first six rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a number of things wrong in your original code, but the following works and should give you guidance about where you were going wrong. Probably the most importnt thing to see is that you should define an empty matrix before the loop, and fill its values within the loop, using the iterator `i` to specify which value you update each time. NB I assume that you are using `Angle` from `library(LearnGeom)`, as you did not specify the source of this function:

```
Nangles = NROW(fish2) - 2
anglematrix = matrix(nr = Nangles, nc=1)

for(i in 1:Nangles) {
  a1 <- as.numeric(fish2[i, ])
  a2 <- as.numeric(fish2[i + 1, ])
  a3 <- as.numeric(fish2[i + 2, ])
  anglematrix[i] <- Angle(a1, a2, a3, label=FALSE)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much dww this worked perfectly. I see exactly what I was doing wrong and this all makes sense.